# Function struct points to other function of other struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, c++14, memory-address

I'm trying to point a structure function to another function of another structure,

Plase consider this:

```
// Main Structure:

typedef struct
{
    int GetValA(int a)
    {
        return a * 2;
    }
} x;


typedef struct
{
    int(*HGetValA)(int); // Pointer function    
} hookx;

// Then

int main()
{
    x v1;

    hookx* v2;

    v2 = (hookx*)&v1; // or 0x0 memory address

    // Now declaring pointer function

    v2->HGetValA = (int(*)(int))&v1.GetValA; // Pointing to function of the main structure.
}
```

for me, this looks good, but at compile time gives me the error:

> [Warning] converting from 'int (x::*)(int)' to 'int (*)(int)'
>   [-Wpmf-conversions]

Answer (score 1):

The pointer points to a member from class/struct does NOT really means to a address, it just points as an offset from `this`.

So the pointer type out of the class/struct (like in your code, `int ()(int)`) is different from the inner (like, `int (::)(int)`).

You have to declare the pointer with a class/struct name that seem to be a scope (and it does).

Comment: it isn't possible without a name?

Comment: It works to adding a keyword `static` before `GetValA()` in this program. but maybe it is not what you write for exactly.